# How can I send list input to SOAP request?

Tags: java, soap, soapui, soap-client

My Soap request is expecting list of user IDs as input.

Below input is working fine from SOAPUI.

```
<UserID>1234</UserID>
<UserID>5678</USERID>
..
```

I tried to give same inputs from Java as an ArrayList but not working. Please advise how can I send input for my soap request from Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can send array in soap request.

```
List<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer[] res = idList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

ArrayList is not understood by the Web Service. You should use types which are understood by WSDL.

Comment: Sorry Amit. UserID is String. So List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] res = idList.toArray(new String[0]); right? Let me try.

Comment: Yes you can do that. Can you show me the WSDL or xsd of your web-service ? I want to see the elemnt types.

Comment: How I can add values to above list?

Comment: idList.add("Hello");  idList.add("World"); like this.

Comment: Sorry for Pain, Why second line Integer[] res = idList.toArray(new Integer[0]); ?, Simply forst line and add values to it and post that to SOAP irght?

Comment: Element type is. <xs:element name="UserID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>